# What is $(A\Delta B) \cap (A\Delta C)$ ??

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is $$(A\Delta B) \cap (A\Delta C)$$
without using a Venn Diagram.

My try: we have
$$(A\Delta B) \cap (A\Delta C)$$
$$\implies ?? $$

please I need help tried (commutative, associative, distributive) rules for ∩ and ∪ and I know the result(I used the table of truth ) but I want the demonstration

Comment: $(A \Delta B)$ is the [Symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of sets $A$ and $B$. It is the union of the two without the intersection.

Comment: Thus: $(x \in A \land x \notin B) \lor (x \in B \land x \notin A)$.Write the same formula for $(A \Delta C)$ and conjoin them.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA i can't understand you ,can you help more please

Comment: $x \in (A Δ B) \cap (A Δ C) \text {  iff  }$ $([(x∈A ∧ x∉B) ∨ (x∈B ∧ x∉A)] \land [(x∈A ∧ x∉C) ∨ (x∈C ∧ x∉A)])$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$x \in A \Delta B \cap A \Delta C \iff x \in [(A -B)\cup(B-A)] \cap [(A -C)\cup(C-A)].$$
But
$$
x \in [(A -B)\cup(B-A)] \cap [(A -C)\cup(C-A)] \iff x \in [(A-B) \cap (A-C)] \cup [(B-A) \cap (C-A)].
$$
Since
$$(A-B) \cap (A-C)=(A \cap B^c) \cap(A\cap C^c)=A\cap B^c \cap C^c$$
and
$$(B-A) \cap (C-A)= (B \cap A^c) \cap(C \cap A^c)=A^c \cap B\cap C$$
we have that
$$
x \in A \Delta B \cap A \Delta C \iff x \in [A\cap B^c \cap C^c] \cup [A^c \cap B\cap C].
$$